# Converting seconds to hours and minutes

Tags: seconds

I am a newbie in C# and having trouble converting seconds to hours and minutes. I manage to extract the value from an xml and have it place in a text box. I am stuck when trying to convert the value on the textbox which is in seconds to another textbox that will give the result in hh.mm.

I have look at the various example even tried to use the Timespan method but the result is not appearing.

Hope you can guide me on the required code to have the desired result to the other text box. The value for seconds is not fixed. It will changed each time a request is made as it is a total time from point A to point B.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: I was using the following code:

private void find_time_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double seconds;
            TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
                                (int)time.TotalHours,
                                time.Minutes,
                                time.Seconds));

The find_time.Text is the location I want to show the hh.mm after the conversion from the seconds.Text which will extract the value from the XML result.

Comment: I manage to find the solution by converting the following:

 //Convertng Trip Time from Seconds and inserting Result into textboxes
                    int seconds_Int;
                    seconds_Int = Convert.ToInt32(seconds.Text);
                    seconds_Int = int.Parse(seconds.Text);
                    var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds_Int);
                    int hh = timeSpan.Hours;
                    int mm = timeSpan.Minutes;
                    int ss = timeSpan.Seconds;
                    hour_min1.Text = hh + "." + mm;